# SSH Tunnel yielding "administratively prohibited: open failed" after a few hours

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, ssh-tunnel

i have a dynamic OpenSSH tunel running as :

```
ssh -N -D '*:1080' user@example.com
```

(OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3, OpenSSL 0.9.8n 24 Mar 2010)

which runs perfectly for a few hours, or a few days, but begin to randomly drop connections (not 100%, only some) yielding:

```
channel 1019: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I googled it but can't find nothing more than this message spowning in cause of server misconfiguration denying completly the tunnel, here the tunnel works some hours before dropping a few requests.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a chance you're encountering a bad link? I'm pretty baffled at that message-the only other thing I could think of was a memory issue-do you have plenty of free RAM on the box you're sshed into?

Comment: I'll check the memory server-side the next time, and wrote it here.

The bad link idea : I think not as if i restart the ssh, it works well again

Comment: New one this day, checked client and server health (cpu, memory, logs) nothing particular.

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: @sybind No, but I continue using ssh -D a lot, without any problem now. Do you experience it ? Which version ? Only a few drops ?

Comment: I did have this problem, somehow fixed it, then I ran into another wall with setting up the routes between the two hosts. The fix may have been related to setting a static arp cache entry..

Comment: `-D *:1080` does not mean what you think it means. You should replace that with `-D '*:1080'` or just `-D :1080`.

Comment: @kasperd what do *you* think `-D *:1080` means?

Comment: @Mandark First of all it will look for all files in the current directory whose name ends with `:1080`. If no such file exists there will be three different behaviors depending on how your shell is configured. If one or more files matching the pattern the behavior will depend on how those files are named. It could even change which server you are logging in to.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks for this instructive paragraph. But as my ssh process *is* working for a few days before starting to slowly break, I don't think it can be related to a path expansion problem. I also don't use nullglob, and don't have any file ending with :1080 but will change in my question to clarify if anyone read it. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW I asked this 7 years ago, and no longer use -D as a daily basis, so I do no longer enconter this bug, which may be fixed since. So if anyone get the exact same symptoms it still make sense, else it does no longer make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the same message when trying to do a port forward to an unreachable destination:

```
ssh example.com -L 1337:example.invalid:80

telnet localhost 1337
```

> me@example.com:~$ channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

Comment: This can't be that, as my tunnel works some hours before starting to fail, i mean, somtime >24h

Comment: I never said it was :)

Comment: @Andrew This saved me!

Answer (score 1):

“Administratively prohibited” is also one of the ICMP control messages. Is it possible a router between the SSH server and the tunnel destination is sending this?

If sniffing is possible, a simple pcap filter with just `icmp` can show you all ICMP traffic.

Comment: I'll try to dump some ICMP packets next time using tcpdump 'icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echo and icmp[icmptype] != icmp-echoreply'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `authorized_keys` with `permitopen`. On server side, /var/log/auth.log contained:

```
Received request to connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 10001, but the request was denied.
```

As I use `autossh` to create a tunnel, I needed two ports: one for connection (10000) and one for monitoring (10001). The problem came with monitoring port.

In my authorized_keys I had this:

```
command="/home/user/tunnel",no-X11-forwarding,no-pty,permitopen="localhost:10000",permitopen="localhost:10001" ssh-rsa AAAA
```

I solved this by replacing `localhost` instances with `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the dropped connections might be a firewall that is overloaded or configured to be overly strict in cleaning up idle connections, somewhere between your SSH connection target and the ultimate target of the forwarded ports.

Once a firewall judges a connection to have been idle for long enough, it may just drop the connection information from its connection state table. If either endpoint of the connection attempts to pass any traffic after that, the firewall will reject the connection (on behalf of the intended destination) since you're apparently attempting to use an existing connection but the firewall no longer has the state tracking information for that connection. So the firewall rejects the packets with an ICMP error message, hence "administratively prohibited".